# Wake on lan not working on some computers on LAN

Tags: windows-10, wake-on-lan

I have 6 computers with win10 on LAN. All of them have all "wake-on-lan options" resolved (BIOS ok, ethernet ok, windows power option Fast boot unchecked) and still only 3 out of 6 of those PCs wake up. I use etherwake on raspberry pi to send magic packets to the computers MAC adresses.

How do I troubleshoot the computers that dont wake up?

Answer (score 0):

make sure they have the same network card driver installed, in the device manager go to your network card properties > advanced > check that wake on magic packet and wake on pattern match are enabled .

You could always try to boradcast the WOL from the same subnet network IE : try from one of those 3 computers that wakes on lan to wake the ones that doesnt wake .

Make sure that you have their MAC Adresses properly go to command prompt type Ipconfig /all and check your address if it matches .

Comment: unfortunately they are not the same hardware so I cant "make sure they have the same network card driver"

Comment: At least make sure the options are set enabled

Comment: the rpi I am sending the packets is on the LAN with them, so that should not be a problem, but I will try that waking from the waked ones
I checked the mac adresses, I will recheck